# How can a JavaScript Array have type String? (lodash isString)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm testing if an object is a string or not like below.

```
const date = '2021-02-05T16:17:26';
const isDateAString = date instanceof String || typeof date === 'string';
```

[Lodash isString](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isString.js), however, also checks to make sure the object isn't an Array. When can that case happen?

Is it for some odd legacy browser behaviour?

Comment: If the value is a String object. `typeof new String("hello")` is `"object"`.

Comment: Yep, but in that case lodash also checks `!Array.isArray(value)` and that's the bit I don't understand.